# Show for a fixed $0<a<1$ that the sequence of functions on $[-a,a]$ defined by $f_n = x^n$ converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I can show very easily that this same sequence of functions does not converge uniformly on (-1,1) and [0,1] but I am having trouble seeing how to prove that the sequence of functions does show uniform convergence on the suggested interval.

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441604/uniformly-convergence-in-compact-sets

Comment: Thanks, but I was instructed it is possible to construct a much simpler proof without Dini's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We go back to the *definition* of uniform convergence.

The limit is clearly $0$ for all $x$ in our interval. We want to show that for any $x$ in $[-a,a]$, and for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is an $N$ **independent of** $x_0$ such that if $n\ge N$, then $|x^n|\lt \epsilon$.

We have $|x^n|\le a^n$. So if $a^N\lt \epsilon$ and $n\ge N$, the desired inequality will hold. Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer greater than $\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x \in [-a,a]$ for $a \in (0,1)$. Now just use the definition.

Note that $\sup_{x \in [-a,a]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{x \in [-a,a]} |f_n(x) - 0 | = |f_n(a)| = a^n$, and $f_n \to f$ uniformly if and only if $\sup_{x \in [-a,a]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 0$. Since $a^n \to 0$ for $a \in (0,1)$, $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.